# How we can remove protection from DNS zone in OCI

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I had the requirement to add canonical name (CNAME) against an Oracle-owned zone, while publishing changes it omitted error “Operation not allowed in protected resource”, Can anyone suggest, how I can get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

Protected zones such as `oraclevcn.com` are read only. Their records are automatically updated by changes you make to your VCN or other OCI resources. You cannot modify them directly.

If you need to add a CNAME pointing at a record in a protected zone I would suggest you create your own private zone in the same view (this can be called whatever you like). You can then add a CNAME to that zone, pointing at the hostname in the protected zone.

Note that CNAMEs cannot be added to the zone apex. E.g. if you created a private zone `mycompany.com` you could not add a CNAME to that hostname, you would have to add it to `something.mycompany.com`.